# Customise performAction of UIActivityTypePostToTwitter

Tags: uiactivityviewcontroller, uiactivity

when presenting `UIActivityViewController`, I want to send the message directly instead of presenting composing dialog when user select "Twitter" or "Facebook".

Is it possible to do this?

or I have to create a new UIActivity to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the Answer is Yes.

I have to write my own activity provider, and custom activites, to achieve what I intended.

The problem is all images displayed in custom activities are black-white, only the skeleton left. I think Apple want to keep an consistent UI, preventing developers provider "Pool" taste images which mess up the whole UI experience.